# How to download something using Python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a python program that allows the user to downlaod whatever they write down (kind of like a little notepad tool). I figured everything out other than how to allow the user to download after they finished. Is there a built in function or a library that could allow this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [wget](https://pypi.org/project/wget/) to fetch url content.

Example:

```
import wget
url = 'www.your_url.com'
filename = wget.download(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're talking about `requests` from python.

You can try something like this:

```
import requests as rq
url = "www.yoursite.com"
ret = rq.get(url)
print(ret.text)
```

You can start with that, but you need to study more about requests.
You can read about it here:

https://pypi.org/project/requests/

https://www.w3schools.com/python/module_requests.asp

I hope that helps you.